# How do i map network drive with User Credentials

Tags: network-share, windows-service

I would like to know how do i map a network drive with user Credentials and is it possible to map network drive with local system account ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local System uses the machine account in an Active Directory domain so provided the DOMAIN\COMPUTER$ account is granted access to the share it will be able to mount and access the share

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc170953.aspx for further details

Comment: but how do i find this acount name ??means from commandline??

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bat file that uses the runas command:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\runas.exe /user:domainorsystemname\username "mapdrive.cmd"

Within the `mapdrive.cmd` you can use the standard `net use drive: \\networkpath\`

This will prompt you for a password, then run the mapdrive command